# rake db:schema:load causes tables to be prefixed again with table_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, schema

I have a need to prefix my tables in schema, but for some reason rails wants to prefix the tables again during db:schema:load. Is there a way to configure rails to use db prefix but not to put it in schema.rb or not to prefix the tables again?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to prefix your tables?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = "casha_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like no -- an actively open Rails issue. (see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4259)

Potential fix for you: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4396

So you could fork Rails and apply that pull request and use it